# How do I check the number of digits consumed by each value in data frame

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to calculate the number of bytes of each value in my data frame, is there a way to do this ?

here is my data frame :

```
  672   635 6740        2   1   3   1   1   1   531 0
  673   635 6740        2   1   3   1   1   1   531 0
  674   635 6740        2   1   3   1   1   1   531 0
  675   635 6740        2   1   3   1   1   1   531 0
  676   635 6740        2   1   3   1   1   1   531 0
  677   635 6740        2   1   3   1   1   1   531 0
```

i want the fallowing result :

```
  3   3   4        1   1   1   1   1   1   3  1
  3   3   4        1   1   1   1   1   1   3  1
  3   3   4        1   1   1   1   1   1   3  1
  3   3   4        1   1   1   1   1   1   3  1
  3   3   4        1   1   1   1   1   1   3  1
  3   3   4        1   1   1   1   1   1   3  1
```

Comment: Why do 531 and 674 take up 3 bytes? Why does 6740 take 4 bytes?

Comment: seems you want to count the number of digits in decimal representation, not the number of bytes.

Comment: yes exactly :) @MassimoCosta sorry i will edit it right now

Comment: If I understand you correctly it is as simple as: `df.applymap(lambda x: len(str(x)))`

Comment: @swenzel thank you a lot, that works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to

1. read the data line by line
2. split the line using space as delimiter
3. use len(item) to get the number of digits

for instance

`digits = [len(item) if item != '' else None for item in line.split(" ")]`

does 2 and 3 for you (if line is the line of text)

or maybe 

`digits = [len(item) for item in line.split(" ") if item]`

if you want to ignore spaces

Comment: hello, could you be more precised for the item ? @Massimo costa

Comment: item is result of split, I'm splitting a single line in items separated by space.